# VSCode Extension: How do I block the UI so user has to wait for something to finish?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a VSCode extension that reaches out to a web service API. Is there a way to block the UI while it waits for a response.

I need this to block because the source file the user is editing may need to update and possibly move to a different folder.